# Deleting Optional 1-to-Many Does Not Set Foreign Key to Null

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have two entities that have an optional 1-to-many relationship defined and configured as such:

```
public class A 
{
   // ...
   public int? BId { get; set; }
   public B B { get; set; }
}

public class B 
{
   // ...
   public virtual ICollection<A> As { get; set; }
}


public class AConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<A>
{
     public A() 
     {
         // ...
         HasOptional(r => r.B).WithMany(r => r.As).HasForeignKey(r => r.BId);
     }
}
```

When deleting on an entity of type B I expect all the entities of type A that have a foreign key to the B entity being deleted to have that BId foreign key set to `null`. The delete operation is defined thusly:

```
public void DeleteB(int bId)
{
    var entity = _context.Bs.Single(b => b.Id == bId);
    _context.Bs.Remove(entity);
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

However this does **not** happen. The entity of type B is successfully deleted, but the BId on the A entities are still non-null and any other calls to .SaveChanges() throw exceptions because those BIds are referencing rows that no longer exist.

How can I delete the B entities in a manner that will nullify the BId properties without having to manually iterate over the collection during the delete operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The foreign keys would only be automatically set to null if the currently associated entities have already been loaded into the context. In other words, when `b` is removed, the associated set of type `A` would only have their `BId` property set to null if those entities of type `A` had already been loaded into the context. Otherwise, EF would not have any knowledge of their existence (unless the EF provider automatically generates SQL set those foreign keys to null...which it doesn't in the SQL Server case).

One option is to do this (if you don't mind loading all those entities):

```
public void DeleteB(int bId)
{
    var entity = _context.Bs.Single(b => b.Id == bId);
    _context.Entry(entity).Collection(b => b.As).Load(); 
    _context.Bs.Remove(entity);
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Another option is to write your own SQL statement and run that.

Comment: I can run an ``update A a set a.BId = NULL where a.BId = @bId`` as ``before delete`` trigger on the A table.